# Can it be implemented in Mathematica in CDF format?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, interactive, wolfram-cdf

Encouraged by the advertisement of the new [Deployment & Connectivity](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/features/deployment-and-connectivity.html) features, I decided to use Mathematica 8 for developing a simple application to be shared with my colleagues. The purpose is to demonstrate user interface for our interactive method of multiobjective optimization. This interface is used for setting some pairwise coefficients for a set of criteria (which is not important in the context my question).

*What is important* is that I need to display a table containing input fields which interact with each other, and in particular can be dynamically replaced with non-interactive contents (e.g. text) during the interaction process.

After developing the application and deploying it to CDF I learned that it does not work in internet browsers (because I don’t use Manipulate function with its very limited capabilities). My application even doesn’t work correctly in the Mathematica player!

The very simplified version of my application is presented below. The question is following: can an interactive application like that (keeping in mind the “What is important” part) be implemented in Mathematica 8 in such a way that it can be shared with other people (mainly on the Windows platform) not having Mathematica installed? If not, could you suggest an alternative platform for implementing such kind of interactive application in an easiest way (Python? Java?).

Thank you in advance.

```
nCriteria = 5;
RatioControl[{i_, j_}] := Dynamic[
   If[Ratio[i, j] === Null,
    If[Ratio[j, i] === Null,
     InputField[Dynamic@Ratio[i, j], Number, FieldSize -> 4],
     N[1/Ratio[j, i]]
     ], Ratio[i, j]
    ]
   ];
ControlTable = Dynamic[
   Grid[
    Table[
     If[i == j, Item["", Background -> GrayLevel[0.7]],
      RatioControl[{i, j}]],
     {i, nCriteria}, {j, nCriteria}
     ], Frame -> All
    ]
   ];
Do[Ratio[i, j] = Null, {i, nCriteria}, {j, nCriteria}];
ControlTable
```

Comment: Likely to get (better) answers at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See the section on `Manipulate` [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4427/363).  It describes how to run code like yours in a dynamic module instead of a manipulate.  You just need to hold your variables as dynamic module local instances, and use initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your CFD.

```
DynamicModule[{}, Dynamic[Grid[
   Table[If[i == j, Item["", Background -> GrayLevel[0.7]],
     RatioControl[{i, j}]], {i, nCriteria}, {j, nCriteria}],
   Frame -> All]],
 Initialization :> (RatioControl[{i_, j_}] := Dynamic[
     If[Ratio[i, j] === Null, If[Ratio[j, i] === Null, 
       InputField[Dynamic@Ratio[i, j], Number, FieldSize -> 4],
       N[1/Ratio[j, i]]], Ratio[i, j]]];
   nCriteria = 5;
   Do[Ratio[i, j] = Null, {i, nCriteria}, {j, nCriteria}])]
```